Looking for a book about a Jewish girl hiding her love for a non-Jewish boy
I read this book in 5th grade about a Jewish girl hiding her love for a boy because he was not from her culture. I believe the title was along the lines of "don't tell" or "keep it a secret."
The cover had a picture of a girl in a shushing motion in black-and-white effect. Her eyes were cut off, so you could only see her lips and finger on her mouth. The rest of the book had a blue background, and the lettering was yellow and/or white if I remember correctly. I read this book back in 2008/2009.
I also don't remember the characters' names. I believe the main girl in the story was the narrator of the book. Which book was this?


It's not Goy Crazy by Melissa Schorr.


The cover art you described is quite distinctive, but it does not immediately match any well-known titles that come to mind. Given that it's not Goy Crazy by Melissa Schorr, here are a few suggestions you could explore:

"Are You There God? It's Me, Margaret" by Judy Blume - This book also deals with issues of religion and young love.

"What I Saw and How I Lied" by Judy Blundell - This book is about a post-WWII love story and has some of the secrecy elements, though it's set against a different backdrop.



Is it possible that the book hasn’t been digitized yet?
